# ReferenceError: waitClk is not defined

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to use zfacts.com national debt clock raw number embed which is by far the most popular debt clock site on the internet.

While there embeds have normally always worked I discovered the raw text national debt clock does not work in the latest version of Firefoxs (works in IEs, Chrome, and Safari).

Can't find anyway contact information to notify ZFacts.com and not sure if this is a Firefox bug or a bug in ZFacts.com code that just only Firefox happens to trip up on.

Here is the link to the embed: http://zfacts.com/node/419. In the top left it should have a countdown of the debt but it's blank in Firefox.

The error in Firefox is "ReferenceError: waitClk is not defined"

Which says the error is line 113 in this file: zfacts.com/giz/G26/GND.php?id=1

Once again if this is a Firefox bug let me know and I can report it to them, or if it's Zfacts javascript I'll keep trying to find a way to notify them. Also yes, I've google searched the error and forums and so far no luck.

UPDATE: While I'd recommend viewing the linked code in your own browser's view source which will format it, rather than copying and pasting all the code here since it's compressed and would show on one line, here is the few lines from that code that in particular is erroring:

```
waitClk();
        function waitClk( ) {                       
            if (typeof(clockObj)=='function') { finish(); return; }
            if ((dlay*=1.3) > 5000) return;         
            setTimeout(waitClk,dlay);
        }
```

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: It's Zfact's code. They create public embeds for most all government sites. That link in my post is the file with the specific code. Since it's compressed I assume it's easily for people to open it directly in their browser's view source which formats it compared to one long line of code in here. But I can copy and paste that file if that would help people more.

Comment: you're defining the function after calling it. You need to define it before calling it.

Comment: @Dave No, functions defined using this syntax are hoisted at the top.

Comment: @plalx true, but apparently not in this case. I'd take the indentation as a clue that the function is actually being defined in some other part of the code though, maybe in a closure or similar.

Comment: Also @heavymark: http://www.jshint.com/

Comment: Unfortunately I can't answer that as the code is by Zfact.com. I tried to reach the owner through Facebook but looks like they haven't posted in a year. However just about every Government site uses Zfacts.com embeds for debt countdowns. Most use the iframe version which works but they don't allow you to change the white iframe background color meaning you can't put it on a colored background. To note the raw version above works in all browsers except Firefox (And use to work in Firefox) but they may have changed there code.

Comment: To view the above code in context the zfacts link above goes straight to that file. If I hear from Zfacts on a resolution I will post here as well.

Comment: @Dave Oh and in regards to "jshint.com" the file that has the error above is a php file. Not sure if that site will help but if it will let me know.